# Java ExecutorCompletionService as API Responder

Tags: java, api, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a server application that listens on a `ServerSocket` for incoming queries. The clients submitting the queries expect to open a socket to the server, pass their query upstream, and then (possibly after a short period of time) read the response to their query from the *same* socket that they used to submit the query.

For this I am trying to use an `ExecutorCompletionService`. Different query classes are passed to different `Callable`s, but all are expected to return a `String` as their result.

All of this is quite manageable until I reach the stage of actually trying to reply to the clients. The `Future` objects are currently all of type `Future<String>`, but I am unable to marry that result (the `String`) up to the appropriate `Socket`.

My solution is about to be to make all of my `Callable`s be of type `Callable<StringSocketPair>` where `StringSocketPair` looks like;

```
public class StringSocketPair {
    Socket sock;
    String content;
}
```

But this all seems a little odd, as now I have to pass the `Socket` to the `Callable` constructor, so that it can return it alongside the `String` result from its `call()` method. All so that I can push the `String` onto the `Socket` in yet another thread which polls `ExecutorCompletionService.take()`.

The other option is to use `Runnable`s instead of `Callable`s and have each `Runnable` task respond on its own `Socket`, but as I have a dozen or so query types, each has their own task object, and I'd rather not have to add a `respondToClient()` call of some kind to the end of every `run()` method for every task object.

There must be a simpler solution to what I would think is a fairly common setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the idea of using a `Runnable`, you could use the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to define the functionality for responding. This would prevent you from having to write that common code for every task as the common code would be placed in the abstract parent class which implements Runnable.

Template Method Pattern:

```
abstract class TemplateSuperClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //some setup code here
        String message = taskWork(...);
        socket.write(message);
        //common cleanup code
    }

    abstract String taskWork(...);
}

class HelloWorld extends TemplateSuperClass {
    String taskWork(...) {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you are probably right to change the Callable to return the tuple of response message and socket.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I had in mind, but I'd still have to actually *call* that method at the final line of each of my `Runnable`'s. Unless I can add some kind of hook to the parent class?

Comment: No. I've edited my answer to include an example of what I had in mind for the use of the template method pattern.